# Making USB to SATA DVD drive show up as sr0 in Debian

Tags: debian, usb, dvd, data-cd

I have a WH16NS40 DVD drive that I want to use on my Debian 12 virtual machine.
The drive is inside a Vantec NexStar DX2 USB 3.0 external enclosure, which connects to the DVD drive via a standard SATA cable.

I had it working and was able to read and write ISOs to discs from my Debian 12 workstation, but when I plugged it into my hypervisor (Proxmox) and passed the USB device through to the VM, it does not show up as sr0 in lsblk and is not in /dev for sr0. The USB part does show up though, as shown below.

lsusb

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 152d:0578 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JMS578 SATA 6Gb/s
```

lshw

```
                 *-usb
                      description: Mass storage device
                      product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
                      vendor: JMicron
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@2:1
                      version: 4.15
                      serial: 0123456789ABCDEF
                      capabilities: usb-2.10 scsi
                      configuration: driver=usb-storage maxpower=30mA speed=480Mbit/s
```

dmesg output:

```
[    1.418561] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0578, bcdDevice= 4.15
[    1.418564] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.418565] usb 2-1: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[    1.418566] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: JMicron
[    1.418566] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCDEF
[    1.422595] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[    1.422697] usb-storage 2-1:1.0: Quirks match for vid 152d pid 0578: 1000000
[    1.422734] scsi host3: usb-storage 2-1:1.0
[    1.422797] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.423715] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
```

Even before I put a disc in the drive, it was present in my workstation as /dev/sr0. But not here.
My workstation is running KDE desktop, are there packages that come with KDE that make detecting these USB enclosures more accurate?

How can I force the OS to consider this USB device a CDROM device and assign it as sr0?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you said yourself, `The USB part`, so it's not about `force the OS to consider this USB device a CDROM device`, but the question is, where's the SCSI part/target? This is either because the adapter cannot detect the CDROM, which could in turn because the CDROM is dead, or the machine's kernel does not have the sr-mod driver built (it could be due to some kernel/module version mismatch problem caused by kernel update and/or misconfiguration as well). And I can't completely rule out that it could be some passthrough hiccup either.

Comment: I just plugged the drive into my workstation again and it works just fine. I guess this is potentially an issue with USB passthrough in Proxmox?

Comment: Maybe, but check `zgrep CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SR /proc/config.gz` *in the VM* first. If it `=m`, further check `modinfo sr_mod`.

Comment: My kernel doesnt have a /proc/config.gz, but `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/.config` does have the line `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_SR=m`. And sr_mod is a module on disk, but is not currently loaded. I tried loading it, but nothing in lsblk. I put sr_mod in `/etc/modules` and rebooted, but still nothing in lsblk.

Comment: Does it show up (in e.g. `lsblk`) of *the proxmox host* (if you do not have it passed through to a VM)?

Comment: I just removed the passthrough and unplug/plugged the drive back into the host, and even threw a disc in it but it is not showing up as sr0 in proxmox either. It shows up as the same USB device as the VM had. I didn't realize the host had an impact on hardware compatibility with passthrough (thought passthrough was a lower level hardware thing).

Comment: Hmm, maybe it has something to do with the USB (e.g. XHCI) host controller of the proxmox machine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my issue, turns out I had USBGUARD running on the host. Allowing the USB enclosure on the host allowed the passthrough to operate and the VM now sees the DVD drive.

Saw `Device is not authorized for usage` in dmesg on the host.
Then ran `usbguard list-devices`
And the USB to SATA device was number 16
`usbguard allow-device -p 16`

Hopefully this will help others avoid such a simple mistake!